# Are corporate wallets visible to public

Tags: transactions

If a company has created a corporate wallet for me to receive funds back to my crypto account is that publicly visible

Answer (score 1):

> **a company has created a corporate wallet for me ...**

Thieves love to create Bitcoin wallets for victims they have deceived.

Whether such a wallet is visible to the victim depends on whether it is real or some sort of fake. Even if it is visible, the criminal creator has control, not the victim.

The inventor of Bitcoin intended that every Bitcoin user create their own wallet by downloading free software which can be used without requiring a customer relationship with any business. They intended that no one ever needed someone else to create a wallet for them.

> **... to receive funds ... is that publicly visible**

**Wallet visibility**

The sort of wallet Bitcoin's inventor created free software for is always visible to the owner and intended to be not visible by anyone else.

**Transaction visibility**

Even though wallets are generally not visible, all transactions are public information. The public transaction data does not explicitly identify the participants in a transaction - so in some sense your involvement is not explicitly visible. Determined investigators *might* be able to identify participants in some cases.